# EOF autoinserted after printing to console

Tags: c, eof

i have 2 .c files. One that prints 1000 pseudorandom numbers to the console, and one that asks a user to input an integer from the standard input (one by one), stores them in an array, and then tries to see if a specified number is in there. The input from the stream is terminated when the user enter `EOF` value, which i automatically convert to `INT_MAX` for consistency.

Now i tried to test the find.c program by `./generate 1000 | ./find 5`

and it works, but i am a bit baffled, because this would suggest that after printing the 1000 values to the screen, ./generate also puts an EOF, otherwise why would ./find terminate the input.

Could anybody please explain how this process happens? (if so)
Thanks.

Comment: What is the "EOF value" you're talking about? Are you referring to `ctrl-d`, the EOF libc constant, or some number like `0` or `-1` that you've made your program interpret as end of input?

Comment: i am referring to cntl-d

Comment: The `EOF` happens automatically when the stream closes, which is what happens when the program terminates. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Yea that is what i mean, thanks! but EOF is supposedly an integer correct? So is this integer generated as the final part of the program ./generate, and that is why it gets passed to ./find?

Comment: More likely the EOF in this case is just the stream being closed and this being detected. Not actually a character.

Answer (score 2):

The "EOF value" is an illusion.

`Ctrl-D` is a terminal feature that signals an end-of-file to the process reading from it. No value is written to the stream.

The program will detect this end-of-file signal by finding that the `read(2)` syscall returns 0, meaning "no bytes read". Libraries translate this into a null pointer, an EOF value, an exception or whatever else they use to indicate that there's no more data to be read.

You get the same 0 byte reads if:

- You try to read from a pipe after closing the write end.

  This is what happens in your pipe example. When `./generate` exits or otherwise closes its stdout, the program reading the output will get repeated 0 byte long reads.
- You try to read from a file when the file pointer is at the end. This is what would happen if you did `./find 5 < somefile` to provide input from a file.
- You're reading from a socket or fifo where the other side closes the connection. This is what would happen if you ran your program as a server with socat or xinetd.

This great and versatile mechanism means that programs that work with user input will automatically work with files, pipes, sockets and anything else that you point it at.